# Pandas: error when implementing Rpy2

Tags: pandas, ipython, rpy2

I am trying to use rpy2 to convert a Pandas panel dataframe object into an R data frame.

When I run `import rpy2.robjects as robjects` I get the following error:

`TypeError: type 'rpy2.rinterface.StrSexpVector' is not an acceptable base type`

Does anyone have a clue on this?

Comment: This looks like it was an error with an old version of rpy2 (eg https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/313/typeerror-type-rpy2rinterfacestrsexpvector). Maybe install the latest version of rpy2 and try again?

Comment: PS have you tried https://github.com/wesm/feather?

Comment: Seems like a issue that was fixed some time ago (see @Noah 's comment). Check your version with `import rpy2; print(rpy2.__version__)`.